How to remove odd numbers from a stack with C?
I need to write&code a program that removes odd numbers from a stack, but how?
I'm learning that know I'm very lost on what to do, in my head my logic is correct but of course it's not.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 

typedef struct n{
    int info;
    struct n *prox;
}node;
 
typedef struct p{
    node *top;
}stack;
 
stack* create (){
    stack *p = (stack*) malloc(sizeof(stack));
    p->top = NULL;
    return p;
}
 
void push (stack* p, int dado){
    node *new = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->info = dado;
    new->prox = p->top;
    p->top = new;
}
 
void shows (stack* p){
    node *aux;
    for (aux=p->top; aux != NULL; aux=aux->prox){
        printf("%i\n",aux->info);
    }
}
 
int empty (stack *p){
    return (p->top == NULL);
}
 
void freestack (stack* p){
    node *aux = p->top;
    while (aux != NULL) {
        node *temp = aux->prox;
        free(aux);
        aux = temp;
    }

    free(p); 
}

int pop (stack* p){
    if (empty(p)) {
        printf("empty stack.\n");
        exit(1); 
    }
    int temp = p->top->info;
    node *aux = p->top;
    p->top=aux->prox;
    free(aux);
    return temp;
}   


void oddnumbers(stack*p){
    node *aux = p->top;
    while(!empty(p)){
        if(aux->info % 2 == 0){
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        else{
            pop(p);
        }
    }
}

 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    stack *p1 = create();
    push(p1,72);
    push(p1,31);
    push(p1,98);
    push(p1,21);
    push(p1,45);
    push(p1,10);
    shows(p1);
    oddnumbers(p1);
    shows(p1);
    freestack(p1);
    return 0;
}

my logic is, while the stack is not empty, the code is going to do an IF, and if the info of the actual node of the stack is even, it's going to move the aux var (the aux var is a var that points to the top of the stack too) to the next node, and if the info of the actual node is odd, it's going to pop.

What is the actual assignment? A stack is characterized by the fact that objects are removed from the top of the stack (last in, first out). Your assignment might be to implement something that is more than a stack, by adding a method to remove items from the middle of the stack. Or it might be to use a stack to remove odd numbers from a collection, such as by popping numbers from one stack one by one and pushing only the even numbers onto another stack. So the correct solution depends on what your actual assignment is.

Pop a number off the stack. If even, push onto a second initially empty stack. Once the first stack is empty, pop off each number from the second one and push onto the original (so the order of the remaining numbers is the same as it was initially)

Please describe the symptoms of how your code fails.

What is the actual observed behavior?

pop doesn't remove the node you're "looking at".  It removes the top node.  So if the top node is even, and you're looking at an odd node further down, it will remove the even node at the top.  Also, even if you manage to remove all odd nodes, the loop will never end as long as there's an even node on the stack, since the stack will not be empty.  Clearly you need to re-think your strategy.

Sidenote: Should I cast the result of malloc (in C)?

oddnumbers() is an odd name for a procedure to eliminate odd numbers.

Although your code identifies the nodes that have odd values -- using aux -- this doesn't have anything to do with what pop does. pop will always remove the top element from the stack, no matter whether it is even or odd; aux doesn't serve a purpose in that.
As you can only pop the top node from a stack, you'll need to pop all values from the stack to be sure you also pop the odd ones. And then you need to push back the even values. That means you need to retain what the even values are which you have popped from the stack. For that you can use another stack.
Some other remarks:

Don't cast what malloc returns
freestack has similar code as pop: it would make sense to have it call pop and avoid this code repetition.
Your output will be hard to interpret as you don't display a separator between the outputs generated by the two calls of shows. Just add a printf between those two calls to clearly separate those two outputs.

Here is your code with those remarks implemented:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
typedef struct n {
    int info;
    struct n *prox;
} node;
 
typedef struct p {
    node *top;
} stack;
 
stack* create() {
    stack *p = malloc(sizeof(stack)); // don't cast
    p->top = NULL;
    return p;
}
 
void push(stack* p, int dado){
    node *new = malloc(sizeof(node)); // don't cast
    new->info = dado;
    new->prox = p->top;
    p->top = new;
}
 
void shows(stack* p) {
    node *aux;
    for (aux = p->top; aux; aux = aux->prox){
        printf("%i\n", aux->info);
    }
}
 
int empty(stack *p) {
    return p->top == NULL;
}
 
int pop(stack *p) {
    if (empty(p)) {
        printf("empty stack.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int temp = p->top->info;
    node *aux = p->top;
    p->top = aux->prox;
    free(aux);
    return temp;
}

void freestack(stack* p) { // Make use of existing functions:
    while (!empty(p)) {
        pop(p);
    }
    free(p); 
}

void oddnumbers(stack *p) {
    stack *evens = create(); // Helper stack
    while (!empty(p)) {
        int info = pop(p);
        if (info % 2 == 0) { // Keep this value
            push(evens, info);
        }
    }
    while (!empty(evens)) { // restore the even values
        push(p, pop(evens));
    }
    freestack(evens);
}

 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    stack *p1 = create();
    push(p1, 72);
    push(p1, 31);
    push(p1, 98);
    push(p1, 21);
    push(p1, 45);
    push(p1, 10);
    printf("Before:\n");
    shows(p1);
    oddnumbers(p1);
    printf("After:\n"); // Separate the two outputs
    shows(p1);
    freestack(p1);
    return 0;
}


The problem with your approach is that you use pop for removing nodes in the middle of the stack. That's not what popdo - it removes the front element.
So you need another function that can remove nodes in e.g. the middle of the stack.
As your stack is based on a singly linked list, you need both a pointer to the element to be removed and a pointer to the previous element.
It could look something like:
void remove_node(stack* p, node *aux, node *prev) {
    if (aux == NULL) exit(1); // Illegal call
    if (prev == NULL) {
        // Remove front element
        p->top = aux->prox;
    } else {
        // Remove non-front element
        prev->prox = aux->prox;
    }
    free(aux);
}

void oddnumbers(stack*p){
    node *aux = p->top;
    node *prev = NULL;
    while(aux != NULL){
        if(aux->info % 2 == 0){
            prev = aux;
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        else{
            node* tmp = aux;
            aux = aux->prox;
            remove_node(p, tmp, prev);
        }
    }
}


A pity remove odd numbers from a stack does not tell using the stack via stack operations, only or any old means giving the correct stack in the end.

@greybeard I can't see any such restriction. Using another temporary stack, it can be done using traditional push/pop operation but it will be slower and use more memory. Since the "internals" of the stack implementation is exposed, I assume that information may be used to implement a fast solution. If only push/pop was allowed, the implementation shouldn't be posted - only the proto-types.

In a stack one begins empty, pushes consecutively, and pops in the reversed order from the top. Only the top is available.
Hence you cannot walk all elements from the stack, all even numbers must be popped too.
The trick is to pop every number and keep the even numbers ... on a new stack.
Mind that the oldest even number now appears on top of that secondary stack.

No, you are good, what the OP has to figure out is that by having the additional struct n pointer he can treat the stack as a linked list -- but that still doesn't eliminate the need to conditionally pop even elements to a new stack. The only alternative is to traverse the stack as a list and delete the odd nodes. Nothing like mixing stacks and lists as you teach new C programmers -- to ensure confusion...

Ohh, okay guys I got it. Probably I'm going to pop ALL tem and push the odds after

Why push "odds" when odd numbers are to be removed?

Please correct tem.

In your implementation you can just chain the odd ones and rest top at the end.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

thank you guys I finished, I did what you guys said.
I created a new stack and if the number was even, I pushed it to the new stack, and the odd ones I just popped them, after all that I pushed the even numbers to the original stack again.

Please see Why and how are some answers deleted?
